# Mesh cutting + triangulation - how to identify holes

Tags: algorithm, mesh, triangulation

I am in the research phase of my programming project. I have to cut a STL mesh with plane and "close" the holes which this cut made - so triangulate them - and make two new meshes this way.

Cutting the mesh seems quite simple.
I also read about a lot of algorithms which should do the triangulation and even some libraries which can do it (Triangle, poly2tri, CGAL)

But, I can't understand how to identify those holes.
And even if I would, when I looked into poly2tri algorithm, there is a function addHole(vector (Point*) Polyline) which indicates, that hole has to be describable with one polyline, but what about something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWv1X.jpg 
Its top view of a cylinder and two "pipes" with longer radius. If I would cut this, the white space would be a hole and I cant represent it with one polyline.

Can someone please explain this me, or share some work which explains this problem so I could understand it properly?

(I searched through stackoverflow and didn't find an answer)

Comment: As you've described it, the remaining part of the problem is much harder than what you've already done: truncating the existing faces at the slicing plane.  You'll need to construct all loops of cut edges and decide the correct direction of each loop using the STL surface normals to infer what's "inside." Since STL doesn't give you useful information about vertex identity, you'll need to infer it from coordinate equality. The loops make a generalized polygon that can be triangulated by a good standard Delaunay or similar algorithm that supports polygons with holes.

Comment: There is some undocumented code in CGAL doing the cutting and the filling. In `master` branch it is in [`CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/internal/clip.h`](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Polygon_mesh_processing/include/CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/internal/clip.h) and in `CGAL/internal/Polyhedron_plane_clipping_3.h` in the 4.9 release. If you want you can try it directly in the Polyhedron demo (Operations->Operations on Polyhedra->Clip Polyhedron)